# jquery html(html_content) function does not seems to be working in IE-7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have and ajaxsubmit method which is defined in the following way

```
var new_options = {
            dataType: 'json', 
            beforeSubmit: function() {
              alert('inside before submit');
              $(".available_script_arguments").each(function(index) {
                argument_id = $(this).val()
                $("td#argument_"+argument_id).addClass("resource_automation_loader");
               });                 
            },
            success: function(data) {
              alert('inside success');
              $(".available_script_arguments").each(function(index) {                    
                argument_id = $(this).val()
                $("td#argument_"+argument_id).removeClass("resource_automation_loader");
                $("td#argument_"+argument_id).html(data[argument_id]).html(); 
                $("td#argument_"+argument_id).html("<span></span>");
                updateTargetArgumentId();
                triggerAdapterResourceAutomation();
              });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert('inside error');
             $(".resource_automation_loader").each(function(){
                // This will hide the loader
                $(this).removeClass("resource_automation_loader");
                // This will display text N.A indicating the resource automation has failed
                $(this).html("<input type='text' value='' placeholder='N.A'></input>");
             });
            }
          };
          $("form#update_resource_automation_parameters").ajaxSubmit(new_options);
```

This function is working proper in Firefox but not working in IE7.

I found out the reason and it came out with jquery html function used in success callback.

as in the success callback data is coming as html(combination of div and select)

after inspecing the data in success callback (given below)

```
<div >
<select arg_val="null">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="0">Corporate Strategic</option>
<option value="1">Business Unit Strategic</option>
<option value="2">Maintenance</option>
<option value="3">Defect</option>
</select>
</div>
```

so this data basically outputs to select list in the view but this is not working in IE7.

Let me know if anyone has any idea on this.

Thanks,
Dean.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `append` instead of the `html`

Answer (score 0):

further to rahul's answer you're constantly selecting the same object through jquery.
When you perform actions in JQuery, it will return the affected object, allowing you to chain your actions.

For example:

```
$("td#argument_"+argument_id).removeClass("resource_automation_loader");
$("td#argument_"+argument_id).html(data[argument_id]).html(); 
$("td#argument_"+argument_id).html("<span></span>");
```

can become:

```
$("td#argument_"+argument_id).removeClass("resource_automation_loader")
                             .append(data[argument_id])
                             .append("<span></span>");
```

which only selects the object once.

Comment: Thanks for giving this solution, but unfortunately this is also not working in IE7